# Soving a specific nonlinear elliptic equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the following elliptic equation:
$$
\Delta u(x)+|\nabla u(x)|^2=f(x).
$$
Is there some consequence of the strong solution to the above equation? For example, $f\in L^p(R^d)$ with $p$ large enough, can we get $u\in W^{2,p}(R^d)$?

Comment: Nonlinear PDEs are tough cookies...

Comment: which dimensionality is u supposed to have? Real variables of d dimensions?

Comment: Yes. The simplest case of real valued in demension $d$. We can also assume that $f\in C_0^\infty(R^d)$.

Comment: but left hand side is one dimensional, how can $f$ be $d$ dimensional? or does $R^d$ in parentheses specify input dimensionality?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I should specify it more clear. The function $f: R^d\rightarrow R$, and we seek a solution $u: R^d \rightarrow R$.

Comment: For quasilinear equations you typically need to do some $C^0, C^1, C^{1,\alpha}$ estimates first (with maximum principle arguments), after which you can treat the equation as a linear one and apply Schauder/$L^p$ estimates to get higher regularity. See e.g. the later chapters of Gilbarg & Trudinger. I'm not sure how much you can say starting with only $L^p$ data - Moser iteration can get you local $C^0$ bounds in terms of $L^p$ bounds on $f$ and $u$, but you have to get this $L^p$ bound on $u$ from somewhere...

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation.